# fetching a result from database having a code value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to retrieve the values from a database table and show them in a php file.
The database table name is profiledetails, it has 6 fields right now (id, Name,dob, gender, district and caste) but value of gender is given as 1 for male, 2 for female and 3 for transgender same way district values are also given in number format. There is an another table for district for storing the value. Same way caste value are stored as 1 for Hindu , 2 for Muslim and 3 for Muslim , and there will be a separate table for storing caste value named as castetable in database.How can I get it to show all the values from the db in a php like this:

```
$sql="SELECT a.id,a.name,a.dateofbirth,a.gender,ca.religion As Category,s.district FROM profiledetails a Left join castetable ca ON ca.id=a.religion Left join districttable s ON s.district=a.district  Where a.id='$is';";
```

$is value have id of a particular student.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>District</th>
    <th>Caste</th>
```

if gender value is 1 it should be printed as male in php page 
Note: there is no separate table for storing gender value. It implies 1 for male and 2 for female but it was not written or stored in any where.

```
<tr>
    <td>123456789</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>12/02/1999</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>New York </td>
    <td>Muslim</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have write all database connection code and query for fetching the result, but iam confused how to compare those values(gender , District and religion) and print correct value. 
Please help to me and Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: please show what you've written so far to fetch the data. Normally if you've got these IDs in one table and the descriptions in another table, you can just retrieve both together from your query using a SQL JOIN, and then it's trivial to display the description on the page.

Comment: query is working and it fetch value for gender as 1 or 2 instead of male or female.

Comment: but you said that the descriptions are held in another table, right? So you can just do a join in your query to that other table using the ID, and get the description as part of the query output in each row. We can help you more easily if you edit the question to show the code you've already written.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  If you're just asking how to get data from a database, compare values, display data, etc. then that's all covered by introductory tutorials on PHP and MySQL.

Comment: please go through my question again

Comment: don't you have a "gender" table as well you can join to? If not, then you should create one with the values and descriptions in, same as your caste, religion, and district ones. For the district and caste ones you're getting those descriptions returned from the query, I can see. So what's the confusion in displaying them on the page? Or don't know you how to get _any_ of the data onto the page? For that you should simply consult one of the hundreds of introductory PHP tutorials available online already.

Comment: P.S. `Where a.id='$is'`. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. A malicious input value in the request could result in your data being stolen, corrupted or destroyed. Please see http://bobby-tables.com/ for an explanation of the issue, and also some examples of how to write your queries safely in PHP (mysqli and PDO examples are available).

Comment: thanks @ADyson for your valuable reply, i can't add any more table for it , i just want to check if the value at gender field is 1, print male .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running below query:

```
$sql="SELECT a.id,a.name,a.dateofbirth,(case g.gender when 1 then 'Male' when 2 then 'female' when 3 then 'transgender' else null end) as gender ,ca.religion As Category,s.district FROM profiledetails a, castetable ca, districttable s where a.religion=ca.id AND a.district=s.district  and a.id='$is';";
```

I guess this will work.

Answer (score 0):

$sql="SELECT a.id,a.name,a.dateofbirth,
CASE WHEN a.gender = 1 then 'Male' WHEN gender = 2 then 'female' WHEN gender = 3 then 'transgender' else null  END as gender
ca.religion As Category,s.district
 FROM profiledetails a, castetable ca, districttable s 
where a.religion=ca.id AND a.district=s.district  and a.id='$is' ";

Comment: What is different between your answer and another answer to the same question?